# В slick slider перестаёт работать автовоспроизведение после клика на стрелку

Tags: slider, slick.js

В slick slider после клика на стрелку перехода к предыдущему или следующему слайду перестаёт работать autoplay, но после клика на любую область страницы, то autoplay начинает работать вновь, а нужно, чтобы и после клика на стрелку autoplay работал дальше. Как можно исправить?

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var $slider = $('.slider');
    if ($slider.length) {
        $slider.slick({
            slidesToShow: 7,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 1500,
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 1024,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 3,
                        slidesToScroll: 3,
                        infinite: true,
                        autoplay: true,
                        autoplaySpeed: 1500
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 600,
                    settings: {
                        autoplay: true,
                        autoplaySpeed: 1500,
                        slidesToShow: 2,
                        slidesToScroll: 2
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 480,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 1,
                        slidesToScroll: 1,
                        autoplay: true,
                        autoplaySpeed: 1500
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autoplay перестаёт работать не после клика, а при наведении на слайдер. 
Установите настройки pauseOnFocus, pauseOnHover в false и будет вам счастье :)

Comment: оказывается всё так просто, спасибо, помогло)

Comment: Пожалуйста, рад был помочь :)